# Using Arcade labelling to sum area of an attribute for a specific a project

Tags: labeling, arcgis-online, arcade

I'm struggling to create an expression to sum the total area of a project for a certain attribute. The areas are continuous so I'd like to be able to create a label that had both the features acres and total acres

The data structure is currently: `ProjectName`, `Type`, `Acreage`

The `Type` is one of two things:

- Useable
- Unusable

[image: Screen shot of data]

`Acreage` is labelling expression to convert sq m into acres.

Is there a way that I could get the label to return the Sum of all `Useable` and `Unusable` depending on the project?

The desired label would look like:

Project - xxx
Type - Usable rent
Acres - xxx

**Total Acres of Usable Rent for Project: xxx**
**Total Acres of Unusable Rent for Project: xxx**

Comment: Apologies that was unclear. I would like two figures on the label. One figure for total useable land and one for unusable land within a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe what you want is possible when creating a *label* as the functions that allow you to access and summarize data from an *entire* layer do not appear to be available when labelling. It seems you are limited to `$feature`, but you can create the text as a pop-up.

To answer your question I have to spoof up some sample data, this is shown below:

[image: Sample data]

You then configure the pop-up and create an expression:

```js
// Get the project, type and acres for feature
var p = $feature["Project"];
var t = $feature["Type"];
var a = $feature["Acres"];

// Create a SQL query to query at a project level for the feature
var q = "Project = '" + p + "'";

// Compute sum area for project/type, this creates a featureset
var fs_stats = GroupBy($layer,['Project','Type'],{name: 'TotalArea', expression: 'Acres', statistic: 'SUM'});

//Create subsets from fs_stats
var fs_Proj = Filter(fs_stats,q); //Creates featureset for just project
var fs_Unused = Filter(fs_Proj,"Type = 'Unuse'"); // A featureset of 1 row
var fs_Used = Filter(fs_Proj,"Type = 'Use'"); // A featureset of 1 row

// Extract out the Total area for the unused type for the project
var TA_Unused = 0;
for(var f in fs_Unused){
 TA_Unused += f["TotalArea"];}

// Extract out the Total area for the used type for the project 
var TA_used = 0;
for(var f in fs_Used){
 TA_used += f["TotalArea"];}

// Create text for pop up
var l = Concatenate(["Project - " , p , TextFormatting.NewLine , "Type - " , t , TextFormatting.NewLine , "Acres - " , a, TextFormatting.NewLine, "Total Acres of Usable Rent for Project:", TA_used,TextFormatting.NewLine,"Total Acres of Unusable Rent for Project: " , TA_Unused]); 

// Return text that becomes the pop-up text
return l
```

I then assigned this expression to the Title and turned off fields

The final output is:

[image: Pop-up]

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. I do have a new issue with this expression.   The 'Acres' field is static and needs to be updated using field calculator.   I have another 'pop up' that calculates the acres using the expression: AreaGeodetic($feature,'square-meters')*0.000247105  Is there a way to use this figure as the expression?   Instead of 'Acres' it would be this?